# How do I write " *value* *plus-minus sign* *value* ", along with text, with annotate of ggplot2, R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, annotate

Here's my problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

a = c(4, 2)
x = c(1:4)
y = c(1:4)

# This works (τ^-1 = 4 s^-1):

l <- paste("tau^-1 ==", a[1], "*~s^-1")
qplot(x, y) + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 3.5, parse=TRUE, label = l);

# But I would like to see something like this ( τ^-1 = 4 ± 2 s^-1): 

l <- paste("tau^-1 ==", a[1], "\u00B1", a[2], "*~s^-1")
qplot(x, y) + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 3.5, parse=TRUE, label = l);
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error in parse(text = lab) : <text>:1:13: unexpected input
1: tau^-1 == 4 ±
                ^
```

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `parse = TRUE` the label will be displayed as described in `?plotmath`. On the help page you can find a table with the avaiable features and the proper syntax.

In your case you just have to use `%+-%` instead of the unicode Symbol `\u00B1` so that R is able to coerce it to an expression.

```
 l <- paste("tau^-1 ==", a[1], "%+-%", a[2], "*~s^-1")
 qplot(x, y) + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 3.5, parse=TRUE, label = l)
```